# Joi validate a string that can contain digits 0-9 but cannot contain only digits?

Tags: javascript, joi

In Joi, is it possible to validate a string with the following restriction:  The string can contain digits 0-9, but cannot include *only* the digits 0-9?

eg:

```
934298234 // false
934298234x // true
```

So the string must contain at least one character other than a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`string.pattern`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#stringpatternregex-name--options---aliases-regex) passing the `invert` option to disallow numbers.

```
Joi.string().pattern(/^\d+$/, { invert: true })
```